# .htaccess masked forwarding for certain folder/directory within domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ftp, forwarding

Let's say I have a domain called www.customer1.com and www.customer2.com. I want to run all the pages of these sites separately... but items found within certain paths, I'd like to reference from one domain to another in a masked forwarded manner for SEO purposes and to avoid having to place files in two different FTP accounts.

The target folders are

```
/images
/pdfs
```

FOr example if a call is made to

`www.customer2.com/images/[any image]` then I want the masked forwarder to kick in to serve a file that is located at `www.customer1.com/images/[filename requested]`. Same goes for anything found after `/pdf/` in the same example.

However all other pages should remain referencing to internal files within.

I have limited understanding of .htaccess and frankly lost as to how to approach anything beyond a very simple 30

Comment: Are these both domains hosted on same host pointing to same DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: No, completely separate accounts although on same server. If it was same doc root that would be a much easier job.

Comment: In that case only way you can do it is by enabling mod_proxy. Can you have it enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you understand the concept here, as the "forwarding" would equate to an external redirect, there is no "masking" anywhere. The closest thing there is is reverse proxying:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(images|pdf)/(.*)$ http://www.customer1.com/$1/$2 [L,P]
```

You need mod_proxy to do this and those rules need to be in the htaccess file in your `customer2.com`'s document root.

You can also do this in `customer2.com`'s server/vhost config:

```
ProxyPass /images/ http://www.customer1.com/images/
ProxyPass /pdf/ http://www.customer1.com/pdf/
```